# Why use pre-measures for the construction of outer measures?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be some non-empty set and let $\mathcal{K}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ countably cover $X$ with $\emptyset\in\mathcal{K}$. Then, given $\nu\colon\mathcal{K}\to[0,\infty]$ with $\nu(\emptyset)=0$, $$
\mu^*(A):=\inf\left\{\sum_j\nu(K_j)\colon (K_j)\in\mathcal{K}^\mathbb{N}, A\subseteq\bigcup_jK_j\right\},\quad A\subseteq X$$
defines an outer measure $\mu^*$ on X.

Now, given a pre-measure $\mu'$ on a semi-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$ they would define an outer measure via the above mechanism which doesn't require $\mu'$ to be $\sigma$-additive and $\mathcal{A}$ to be a semi-ring of sets.

So, why do some texts use pre-measures and semi-alegbras to construct outer measures this way? Is this motivational, only?

Comment: Isn't using your first definition equivalent to using a premeasure?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly @user144410? Pre-measures are defined on semi-algebras with numeric values and with being zero on the empty set and semi-algebras contain $X$ (and $\emptyset$), so do countably cover $X$, but they certainly exhibit more structure than needed, no?

Comment: I mean the outer measure that you get? @Ramen When pre-measures are used it is usually in the context of extensions: every pre-measure gives rise to an outer measure which is defined for all subsets, and its restriction to sigma algebra gives a measure. Also see the Hahn–Kolmogorov theorem.

Comment: So pre-measures and semi-algebras are the simplest structures that allow me to extend(!) to some measure? That is, if I wanted $\mu(A)=c$ and I'd include $A$ in $\mathcal{K}$ and had $\nu(A)=c$, I could not be sure of it if $\mathcal{K}$ isn't at least a semi-algebra and $\nu$ a pre-measure? @user144410